# Webcam recognised, can't see picture or stream video

Tags: lubuntu

I'm having problems with using my Lubuntu 17.04. This is my first time using Linux.

I tried to install my webcam (plugged it into usb slot),  opened guvcview and pop up window says:

Guvcview error    could not start a video stream in this device.

you seem to have video devices installed.  Do you want to try one?

Device: Logitech quickcam zoom

when i select this and press OK, the guvcview control window opens with another identical error box over the top of it.

any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to AU. It's best to ask one question at a time. This way, we can answer without writing a novel, and you can get some of the problems solved. It's also advisable to provide all relevant info, hardware make and model, error messages, etc. Broad and vague question tend to get little attention here.

Comment: We'll probably put this on hold as being *too broad*, for the reasons @mikewhatever has outlined. But if you **[edit]** this to remove all but one of your questions (and also provide as many details as possible about it), then it will be reviewed for reopening.

Comment: 17.04 is a semi-unstable version, so not everything may be supported yet. If you are looking for Long Term Support - (LTS), I would suggest porting back to 16.04

Comment: Thank you for the responses, but as i'm absolutely positive that all my problems are linked, that is the problem.    My Friend who helped with the install has used linux (not lubuntu) for four years and it took us both one whole day just to get my MAudiophile soundcard to work, and that is using an audio cable on the digital coax out not the phono jacks.                      David, how do I port back to 16.04?  That sound a very logical solution.  Do yopu need to know my hardware?

Comment: Not just that you're asking lots of things, you're not providing us with any detail.  It'd be nice to get some detail on any of these issues. What, for example, happens when you try to [install Skype](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/)?

Comment: Oli, a pop up window with a button to install appears, i press it, another flashes up saying installation 9% complete, then vanishes after less than a second, after that nothing.

Comment: edited question, hope that helps.

Comment: Port is a wrong word here @Jeff You will have to reinstall 16.04 over 17.04

Comment: Before you reinstall everything, let's just look at this webcam. It's going to be a problem in 16.04 too so there's no harm spending a minute to see what the problem actually is. Could you [edit] your question to add details about what you've actually done? Why do you think the system recognises it? How are you testing it?

Comment: @oli, question is now edited with your suggestions, what now?